# Изменение поля input

Tags: ajax

как отследить изменение поля, onchange не работает потому что программно изменение поля идет. как поступить?

Answer (score 1):

Можно заменить input.value на атрибут с getter и setter. Способов много, вот самый простой, но не работающий в старых браузерах:

```
var val= input.value;
input.value={
    realValue: val,
    get() {
        // getter 
    },
    set(val) {
        // setter
    }
}
```

Больше способов создать getter и setter можно найти здесь:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/66242/

Comment: че то вообще не пойму и как тут можно отслеживать?

Comment: set(val) {
        // setter тут писать функцию которую выполнять?
    }